# Trying to refactor a function with a shorthand

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to write `for` loop here via list comprehension:

```
    def calc(uno):
        count = 0
        for num in uno:
            count += 1
        return count

    print(calc('something'))
```

The draft is:

```
     def calc(uno):
         count = 0
         count = [count += 1 for num in uno]
         return count

    print(calc('something'))
```

Unfortunately, I'm receiving the error in `count += 1`.

Comment: your indentation is wrong -please fix

Comment: you are recreating an inefficient `print(len("something"))` - why?

Comment: you cant use list comps like that - there is (currently, wait for 3.8) no backreferencing

Comment: You could use `return sum( (1 for _ in uno) )` instead ...but thats also worse then `len()` directly

Comment: Why would you want to use a list comprehension? You are not building a list. Put differently: **do not use list comprehensions to replace loops unless you are building a list**. A list comprehension *always* builds a list, and building one when you do not actually want a list is a waste of time for Python.

Comment: I wasn't using len(), because the task was to omit using len(). 
Many thanks to everyone for your interest and comments ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions create lists, so if you want to write your `for`loop with a list comprehension, it would look like:

```
def calc(uno):
     return sum((1 for num in uno))
```

You create a list of `1`s and then you sum them. List comprehensions cannot sum on their own (at least not the way you want).

edit: Indeed, no need for a list, generators are enough, thanks a lot for the comments.

Comment: replace with `return sum( (1 for _ in uno) )` to avoid creating a list instance in the first place - marginally faster

Comment: Drop the `[...]` square brackets altogether. You can solve this with a generator expression without having to build a list first.